# How to continue a loop if a duplicate value is found VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a large data set (we're using excel macros).  Some of the values are duplicated in the row or rows after:

```
 A     B       C       D
1234  300    2001    389
6546  300    2005    485
8631  124    9583    562
1234  500    2001    389
6546  500    2005    485
8631  500    9583    562
```

In this example B2 is a duplicate of B1.  I need away to determine if the next row/observation is a dup (I'm only worried about 1 column).  The trouble is, it may be duplicated over multiple rows; it may not just be 2 rows of dups.

The goal would be to remove the dup when they exist.  The above "should" look like this:

```
1234  300    2001    389
6546         2005    485
8631  124    9583    562
1234  500    2001    389
6546         2005    485
8631         9583    562
```

I can sort through the column to the end, but i'm not sure how to loop an check after i find a match

```
Sub Dups()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Range("B" & i).Value = Range("B" & i + 1).Value Then
       For ii = 1 To LastRow 

       //check next rows (same column until i dont have a dup.. then 
          remove 
        them

       Next ii


    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

```
   A          B       C          D               E
11/5/2018   3944    -17.44    -17.44           2000
11/5/2018   3945    0.00      -17.44           2000
11/5/2018   3946    0.00      -25.00           2001
```

[image]

[image: bszIZ.png]

Answer (score 0):

This should remove every duplicate after the first instance, using a dictionary.

```
Sub dupes()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dupedict As Object

    Set dupedict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Can early bind if you add in the scripting runtime reference
    With ActiveSheet 'Make this an explicit reference
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If Not dupedict.exists(.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
                dupedict.Add .Cells(i, 3).Value, ""
            Else
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = ""
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

This will remove only duplicates that immediately follow the original.

```
Option Explicit

Sub dupes()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dupecheck As String
    With ActiveSheet 'Make this an explicit reference
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        dupecheck = ""
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If dupecheck = "" Or dupecheck <> .Cells(i, 3).Value Then
                dupecheck = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            Else
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = ""
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is removing values that are not dups

Comment: Shouldn't be, I am unable to recreate an instance where it does. Could you give me an example that I can test?

Comment: That is strange.

Comment: Sorry - removed my last comment.  Yes I'll give examples where it is not working.

Comment: Under the end sub above.  It removed the value C-3.  Column D is a copy column of C for reference.  C3 should have remained -25

Comment: in the picture example, it removed values that were not dups at all.

Comment: It does not do that on my end. Are you sure you changed all the cell references to be Column C instead of Column B like in my answer? Using your 6 rows that you edited in, the only thing it removes for me is the second -17.44 everything else is still there.

Comment: Yes - i changed the argument to point to the correct cell in the .Cells() method

Comment: Just edited in the proper ones anyway. I'm not sure what it could be then, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I debugged and added a few dummy columns.  Its behaving as if the first 2 characters - after finding a dup - are "stored" in a memory of sorts.  It recognized -100 as a dup of -10.

Comment: Note i added this: dupedict.RemoveAll  after the Else and value="" and it seems to be working

Comment: If you remove all from the dupedict it shouldn't delete anything at all because you are clearing it's contents. There will never be more than a single entry in the dictionary.

Comment: You don't have the two loops from the code in your question, applied to the code in my answer do you?

Comment: No, i do not have two loops.  I had your code copy+paste and only changed the column reference

Comment: for the delete of records - i'm not sure then.. its def removing items that are not dups to the item above.  For example, in the data set there will be more instances of "-17.44".. but i dont need all of them removed, just the instances where they duplicate the row above it.

Comment: I added a larger data set to test as requested.. column "B" is the use case.

Comment: Ohh, you only want to delete duplicates that are immediately following?

Comment: yes - that is correct; all of the dups that immediately follow. it could be 1, or more rows.. but if they "follow" i dont need them.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the dictionary function which will record all the existing value. Proposed codes like following:

```
Sub RemoveDups()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set eleDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If eleDict.Exists(Range("B" & i).Value) Then
        'remove the cell value
        Cell(i, 2).Value = ""
    Else
        eleDict(Range("B" & i).Value) = 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is giving this error:
"User-defined type not defined"